How to mock and test one exact method call in service and ignore all other method calls
I have a log class:
class LogHelper
{
    public static function log(string $type, string $message, array $context = []): void
    {
        Log::channel('test')->{$type}($message, $context);
    }
}

And from service I am calling:
    $test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222']);
    $test->log('notice', 'test5678', ['3333' => '4444']);

Now in test I want to mock LogHelper service and check if specific call was done, in current example I want to check if this call is done:
$test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222']);

But at the same time I want to ignore other calls to that method, in current example this one:
$test->log('notice', 'test5678', ['3333' => '4444']);

This is what I tried so far:
    $this->mock(
        LogHelper::class,
        function (MockInterface $mock)  {
            $mock
                ->shouldReceive('log')
                ->withArgs(function ($type, $name, $context) {
                    $this->assertSame('notice', $type);
                    $this->assertSame('test1234', $name);
                    $this->assertSame(['1111' => '2222'], $context);
                    return true;
                });
        }
    );

And that is working when only that exact call to service was made and no other.
Acceptance criteria is just to check if that call was made:
$test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222'])

and ignore all other method calls.
Test should assert true for all of this cases:
1.
    $test->log('notice', 'test', ['test' => 'test']);
    $test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222']);
    $test->log('notice', 'test5678', ['3333' => '4444']);




    $test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222']);
    $test->log('notice', 'test5678', ['3333' => '4444']);




    $test->log('notice', 'test', ['test' => 'test']);
    $test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222']);




    $test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222']);

and false if this call was never done:
 $test->log('notice', 'test1234', ['1111' => '2222']);

